# Como fazer um deploy de container pelo azure portal?

Tags: docker, microsoft-azure

Como fazer o deploy de um container docker no azure somente utilizando o portal?

Todas as explicações que vejo são usando o `AZURE CLI`, gostaria de saber se há como fazer sem utilizar o `AZURE CLI`.

Comment: [Isso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-portal) resolve seu problema?

Comment: +1 tenho interesse em saber sobre também, até porque irei precisar daqui uns dias.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda tuxpilgrim. Obrigado!

Comment: @RodrigoBatista conseguiu fazer o deploy? Se sim, adicione a solução pro caso de mais alguém precisar ;)

Comment: Sim é possivel usando o Azure Container Instance, o Microsoft Docs tem o tutorial explicando o deploy via portal e via CLI: Portal: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal CLI: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart